# Adding image in folder and its name in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am just a begginar in this programming language and I couldn't solve the problem that I need to add images in folder and saving its name in database. I looked every website but they just doing it different way. By the way my database is already connected. If there is anyone can help me that will be good. Because it's been 4 days I am trying and looking.

```
namespace OrnekProje.Controllers

{
    public class HaberEkleController : Controller

    {

        HaberlerEntities ent = new HaberlerEntities();

        public ActionResult Index(int id)

        {

            Tbl_Haber kategori = ent.Tbl_Haber.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

            ViewBag.KategoriListesi = new SelectList(ent.Tbl_Kategori.ToList(), "Id", "KaategoriAdı", "0");

            return View("HaberEkle", kategori);
        }

        public ActionResult HaberEkle()

        {

            ViewBag.KategoriListesi = new SelectList(ent.Tbl_Kategori.ToList(), "Id", "KaategoriAdı", "0");

            return View(new Tbl_Haber());

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult HaberEkle(Tbl_Haber haberobjesi, HttpPostedFileBase uploadfile, object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            string ImageName = Path.GetFileName(haberobjesi);
            var url = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("//images//"));
            ent.Tbl_Haber.Add(haberobjesi);

            ent.SaveChanges();

            ViewBag.Sonuc = " Haber kaydedildi";

            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = haberobjesi.Id });

        }



    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view, ensure the form's `enctype` is set to `multipart/form-data`. Also, you should set the `name` attribute of the input to `uploadfile`.

**Like this:**

```
<input type="file" name="uploadfile" />
```

Your code needs a bit of clean up too.

```
public ActionResult HaberEkle(Tbl_Haber haberobjesi, HttpPostedFileBase uploadfile) 
    { 
    string ImageName = Path.GetFileName(uploadfile.FileName); 
    var url = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images"),ImageName); 
//Save
    uploadfile.SaveAs(url);
    ent.Tbl_Haber.Add(haberobjesi);
    ent.SaveChanges(); 
    ViewBag.Sonuc = " Haber kaydedildi";
     return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = haberobjesi.Id }); 
    }
```

Comment: the code is giving me an error that the part of the path is not found. And I also have <input type="file" name="uploadfile" /> this part in my code.

Comment: Hard for me to know what's wrong. Be sure to place a break point on the url variable to see it's value. Also, be sure that there is a directory in your project named image.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, I am gonna try my best  :)